# Laptop sleeps while high GPU usage

Tags: laptop

My laptop Dell Vostro 14 sleeps while gaming or video rendering (specifically when GPU is used). Initially windows 10 was installed. I've reinstalled Windows 10 and now reinstalled Windows 8.1. Also, I've checked all power settings but my problem is not solving.

Can someone help to to solve the issue!.

Comment: Downgrading the OS certainly isn't a solution. Unless Win8.1 is the original OS version then it could only make it worse. But if Win8.1 is the original OS then your notebook isn't new and perhaps the hardware has problems. The best advice is to contact your tech support and perform the tests they suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Changing OS doesn't effect your power setting. It seems like there will be issue in your power setting, when you play games and videos, then your system remains idle and it goes to sleep mode and another probability is problem in your graphics card.So first you need to follo the steps and if it doesn't work then check with your tech support.
1. Login to your PC as admin.
2.Go to Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> Power Options
3.select change advance power setting
Then select the appropriate time for sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. 
I disabled Intel turbo boost by lowering the maximum processor state to 98%. 
It also lowers maximum CPU usage to 2.4 GHz, but it solves the problem. 
The only difference now is that games start with a negligible delay. 
Windows make no difference.